# how to use lightbox2 to show video in my page

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox

First of all my site does not use Drupal.So any alternatives for a popup video player funcionality would be appreciated.

I want to show a popup you tube video player in my web page.I downloaded lighbox from the
following link: http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/lightbox2-6.x-1.11.zip

I extracted the zip file into my sites root

I added the following lines in my page header:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/lightbox2/css/lightbox.css?1" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/lightbox2/js/auto_image_handling.js?1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lightbox2/js/lightbox_video.js?1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lightbox2/js/lightbox.js?1"></script>
```

and the following in the body:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0gBtF_awV2o" rel=lightvideo[width:500px;height:400px;]>
    <img src="sample" alt="Live TV">
</a>
```

But the video opens up in a new tab and not as a popup.Where am i going wrong?I cant find tutorials for this anywhere, although i have this kind of code in many other pages with popup videos.

*Edit:* Used shadowbox. Opens up youtube page instead of popup!

*Edit:* Problem solved! Got Shadowbox to work. It's brilliant and easy. The commercial licence costs $20 though.

Comment: Check out my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548589/using-lightbox2-to-display-video/41740013#41740013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are either not calling jQuery or lighbox correctly.

Make sure the have the two `src` correct.

I'm not sure I understood your question but you cant display video with lightbox, it says so in the FAQ and it recommends [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/).

You could also use something [videolighbox](http://videolightbox.com/) or any out there.

Good luck!

Comment: @Trevor is right, it's always better to download from the original sourde see [His answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691700/how-to-use-lightbox2-to-show-video-in-my-page/4692446#4692446)

Comment: The guys at thick box say that i should use shadowbox.I did, but to no avail!

Comment: But its commercial version is paid.Plus the site that i was given for reference uses LightBox2.So my client would probably prefer such a solution

Comment: @Mithun Madhav Oh! hadn't though about that (always personal in my case) anyway glad you found it!

Answer (score 0):

I would [download Lightbox 2 from here](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/#download) and see if it works any better.

Comment: Sorry Lightbox2 was i was using.My cms is Skadate and not Drupal.Is this the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because the lightbox.js file included in the Drupal module is a modified version that uses the Drupal.settings variable, which if you don't use Drupal, is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Lightbox2 video does work in drupal.

You have to enable video support in the lightbox2 settings 
The url: yourdrupal.com/admin/config/user-interface/lightbox2

The flv player should be empty if you don't have one.