# Using Lightbox2 to display video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox2

Site: http://blieque.comli.com/motion

Before I start, I know there are many alternatives to Lightbox2 (Lokesh Dhakar's) to display videos but I want to avoid using three different JavaScript things, already using MooTools and JQuery as I'd like to keep HTTP requests to a minimum, as well as disk usage.

As it comes, Lightbox2 does not support videos, full stop. However, I noticed that the JavaScript was essentially taking the contents of an `a`'s `href` attribute and placing it in an `img`'s `src` attribute when the light-box was open. As far as I can see, changing this `img` to an `iframe` (done) and setting the anchor tag's `href` to `youtube.com/embed/*video-id*` should generate an `iframe` containing that YouTube video (replacing `watch?id=` with `embed/` presents a full screen version of the video.

I then also added JavaScript for width, height and frameborder attributes on top of the default `class="lb-image"`. Now when the page is loaded and the Lightbox called it creates an empty window. If you inspect the code you can see all the attributes are there but the page in the frame frame isn't loaded, just creating an empty `head` and `body` tag.

I was just wondering if it was a server problem or a code problem and if so, how to fix it. If there any way to make it work?

Thanks

**Note: I'm NOT using Drupal so the `lightvideo` option is not available.**

Comment: Did you get any further with this?

Comment: @Samuroid I don't think I did. Are you trying the same thing? I might be able to help; I have a lot more experience now then I did do.

Comment: I cant find anything else on this? any luck?

Comment: @BenClayton Sorry for the delay. What are you trying to achieve? What do you currently have? I might be able help, although I didn't ever get it working back in 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone still is looking for solution.

I had same problem in my project. Not with youtube iframe but it’s not difficult to implenet it. Lightbox2 cannot be extended so i wrote simple class whose adding listener and observer. For proper displaing require is that video have a poster with the same sizes. That’s the fastest way to keep corret sizes of popup.

In href required is to add dataset href with image url

```
<a href="POSTER_URL" data-href="VIDEO_URL" data-lightbox="Videos">
Open Lightbox
</a>
```

SCSS to cover image in popup and set fade effect while loading

```
.lightbox {
  .lb {
    &-outerContainer {
      video {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 9999;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        &:hover, &:focus {
          border: none;
          outline: none;
        }
      }
      &.animating {
        video {
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
    }
    &-container {
      position: relative;
      .lb-image {
        border: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And JS class which one create and set video into popup. Maybe little messy but i don't care. It's only quick solution.

```
class LightBoxVideo {
    constructor() {
        this.videos = {};
        this.lightBoxVideo();
    }

    lightBoxVideo = () => {
        this.setEvents();
        this.setMutationObserver();
    }

    setMutationObserver = () => {
        const observer = new MutationObserver(mutation => {
            const imageMutations = mutation.filter((m) => {
                return m.attributeName === "src" && m.target.className === 'lb-image'
            });
            
            const overlayDisplay = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.lightboxOverlay'), null).display;
            if("none" === overlayDisplay) {
                this.removeVideoElement();
            }
            
            if(imageMutations.length > 0) {
                if(this.videos[imageMutations[0].target.src]) {
                    this.removeVideoElement();
                    this.setVideoElement(this.videos[imageMutations[0].target.src]);
                }
            }
        });

        observer.observe(document.body, {
            childList: false,
            attributes: true,
            subtree: true,
            characterData: false
        });
    }

    setEvents = () => {
        const videoLinks = this.findVideoLinks();
        videoLinks.forEach((link) => {
            this.videos[link.href] = link;
            link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                this.removeVideoElement();
                this.setVideoElement(e.target);
            });
        });
    }

    setVideoElement = (element) => {
        const lightbox = document.querySelector('.lightbox')
        const container = lightbox.querySelector('.lb-container');

        const videoElement = this.createVideoElement(element);
        container.prepend(videoElement);
    }

    removeVideoElement = () => {
        const lightbox = document.querySelector('.lightbox')
        const container = lightbox.querySelector('.lb-container');
        const video = container.querySelector('video');

        if(video) {
            container.removeChild(video);
        }
    }

    createVideoElement = (element) => {
        const video = document.createElement('video');

        video.setAttribute('poster', element.href);
        video.setAttribute('controls', 'true');

        const source = document.createElement('source');
        source.setAttribute('src', element.dataset.href);
        source.setAttribute('type', 'video/mp4');

        video.append(source);

        return video;
    }

    findVideoLinks = () => {
        const hrefs = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-lightbox]');
        const regex = /\.(mp4|mov|flv|wmv)$/;
        if(0 === hrefs.length) {
            return [];
        }
        return Array.from(hrefs).filter((href) => {
            return !! href.dataset.href.match(regex);
        });
    }
}
```

To preview how it's work - codepen here: https://codepen.io/PatrykN/pen/RwKpwMe